# Section counter fails in table of content. (Put all as 0)

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, xetex, counters

Why the counter (`\arabic{section}`) put all sections as 0 in table of contents?

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\renewcommand\thesection{Section~\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}[1.5em]{\large}
{\thesection\hspace{1cm}}
{}
{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{1}

\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}

\chapter{2}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation, is that, when you write `\thesection` in `\titlecontents`, it uses the value of the `section` counter at the time of code writing – and this counter has not yet been incremented. What you must use is the value written in the `.toc`file, and this one is accessed to with `\thecontentslabel`, as mentioned in the documentation.

Here is a working code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{Section~\thesection}{1em}{}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}[1.5em]{\large}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace{1cm}}
{}
{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}

\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}

\chapter{Two}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}
\section{Here}

\end{document}
```

[image]

B.t.w. do you not want the section page numbers in the table of contents?

Comment: The page number I already have, I just put this MWE to show the problem with the counter! Thank you!

Comment: But Can I create a counter with "\thecontentslabel"? Because I need to manipulate this number (I.e.) change the number system as Arabic, Roman numbers, but this seem to bug when I put a converser Like "\Roman" and a script that I use to convert for Arabic system.

Comment: The problem is that you've re-defined  `thesection` instead of using `\titleformat{\section...`. I'll try to find a solution (I've already done something like that a couple of years ago).

Comment: I removed the re-definition of thesection, and now I have the format: 1.1,1.2...2.1,2.2... And my scripts converts just the first digit.

Comment: I've added  a  `\titleformat` line. Could  you test  if your converters work? B.t.w. do you want a different section counter display in the body of the document and in the table of contents?

Comment: For converts not, unfortunately. I want a counter to use in table of contents, that I can number all the sections and convert that numbers to other formats. Actually, the converter just convert the first symbol. like I.1, I.2 etc